# How to know which records cause an issue when I run a SQL MERGE statement in Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I was running below codes in python. It's doing a merge from one table to another table. But sometimes it gave me errors due to duplicates. How do I know which records have been merge and which one has not so that I can trace the records and fix it. Or at least, how to make my code log hinted error message so that I can trace it?

```
# Exact match client on NAME/DOB (not yet using name_dob_v)
    sql = """
    merge into nf.es es using (
        select id, name_last, name_first, dob 
        from fd.emp
        where name_last is not null and name_first is not null and dob is not null
    ) es6
    on (upper(es.patient_last_name) = upper(es6.name_last) and upper(es.patient_first_name) = upper(es6.name_first)
        and es.patient_dob = ems6.dob)
    when matched then update set 
        es.client_id = ems6.id
      , es.client_id_comment = '2 exact name/exact dob match'
    where
           es.client_id is null -- exclude those already matched
       and es.patient_last_name is not null and es.patient_first_name is not null and es.patient_dob is not null 
       
       and es.is_lock = 'Locked' and es.is_active = 'Yes' and es.patient_last_name NOT IN ('DOE','UNKNOWN','DELETE', 'CANCEL','CANCELLED','CXL','REFUSED')
    """
        log.info(sql)
        curs.execute(sql)
        msg = "nf.es rows updated with es6 client_id due to exact name/dob match: %d" % curs.rowcount
        log.info(msg)
        emailer.append(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't know, `merge` won't tell you. You have to actually **find** them and take appropriate action.

**Maybe** it'll help if you select distinct values:

```
 merge into nf.es es using (
        select DISTINCT                       --> this
          id, name_last, name_first, dob 
        from fd.emp
        ...
```

---

If it still doesn't work, then join table to be merged with the one in `using` clause on all columns you're doing it already and see which rows are duplicate. Something like this:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT d.id,
                 d.name_last,
                 d.name_first,
                 d.dob
            FROM fd.emp d
                 JOIN nf.es e
                    ON     UPPER (e.patient_last_name) = UPPER (d.name_last)
                       AND UPPER (e.patient_first_name) = UPPER (d.name_first)
           WHERE     d.name_last IS NOT NULL
                 AND d.name_first IS NOT NULL
                 AND d.dob IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY id,
         name_last,
         name_first,
         dob
  HAVING COUNT (*) > 2;
```

Comment: Ah, yes - I edited the answer (added some more info - useful, I hope), but forgot to let you know so I'm doing it now. See if it helps.

Comment: Thank you! It's very helpful!